# Detecting partial rows in SSIS

Tags: error-handling, ssis, delimiter, script-component

**Situation:** A tab delimited row from a flat file source is missing columns at the end of the row. The rows are delimited by `{CR}{LF}` in the Flat File Connection Manager, and the last column is delimited by `{CR}{LF}` as well. All other columns are delimited by `Tab {t}`. SSIS is importing the row.

Example:

Column_1`{t}`  Column_2`{t}`   Column_3`{t}`   Column_4`{CR}{LF}`

123`{t}`   123`{t}`    123`{t}`        123`{CR}{LF}`

123`{t}`   123`{CR}{LF}`

123`{t}`   123`{t}`    123{`{t}`   123`{CR}{LF}`

123`{t}`   123`{t}`    `{t}`   `{CR}{LF}`

123`{t}`   123`{t}`    123`{t}`    123`{CR}{LF}`

**Problem:**  A partial row that does not have the remaining columns tab delimited (see row 2 above) treats the following row as a part of the current row, while a row containing the tab delimited columns that are blank (see row 4 above) does not.

**Desired Output:** An error is desired to signal a partial row.

What is the best method to check for partial rows in the middle of a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that pre-denali (2012) SSIS fails if the missing column when parsing. This is fixed in 2012 by always checking for the row delimiter.

See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2011/07/17/flat-file-source-changes-in-denali.aspx

Work arounds for this issue in pre-2012 SSIS include writing your own parser (this is what we chose to do), converting the data before parsing it, or using the Flat File Source just to parse rows.